# Issue with downloading Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

When i attempt to download Ubuntu desktop, I get a message to go to a website about Windows file associations or extensions.  There are a number of options there, but i don't know which to select or how to proceed.  Is there a way around (or thru) this?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do something with the .iso file?

Answer (score 3):

Your Windows is trying to open the iso file instead of saving it to the hard drive, and since Windows doesn't open iso files, it points you to the web.

Download Ubuntu again, and this time save the iso image to somewhere easy to find, like your desktop.